# mat-checkbox checked, but not rendering the check mark

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-material2

I have a component that contains a `mat-list-item`, which, when clicked, will toggle a checkbox's state between checked, indeterminate, and unchecked (in that order). Each list item has a number value that adds to a total as well when checked, subtracts from the total when indeterminate (shown here as the property `mitigated`), and again has a value of zero when it isn't selected.

I got the UI looking & working correctly with the `click` event bound to the `mat-list-item`. When the list item is clicked, the checkbox appears checked. Clicked a second time, the styling is applied so it's got strike-through on the text & the checkbox is in the `indeterminate` state. Clicked a third time, it resets to unchecked. The math is working correctly with this behavior as well.

However, when I click on the **checkbox itself**, not the list item, the checkbox does not render as checked, even though my `console.log` statement shows true after it's clicked. It adds the numeric value of the list item each time it's clicked & the UI doesn't reflect any changes. I can't figure out why this is happening.

I could bind the event just to the checkbox, but I want the user to be able to select the entire list-item for ease of use.

Component:

```
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { Risk } from './risk.model';
import { MatCheckboxChange, MatCheckbox } from '@angular/material';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-risk',
  templateUrl: './risk.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./risk.component.css']
})
export class RiskComponent {
  @Input('risk') risk: Risk;
  @Output() riskSelected = new EventEmitter<number>();
  mitigated: boolean;
  countScore: boolean;

  constructor() { }

  onSelect(c: MatCheckbox) {
    this.mitigated = c.checked && !this.mitigated;
    c.checked = ((c.checked && this.mitigated) || !c.checked);
    console.log('Checked: ', c.checked); // logs true, not rendered in browser
    this.countScore = c.checked && !this.mitigated;

    this.changeScore(c);
  }

  private changeScore(c: MatCheckbox): void {
    let changeValue: number;

    if (!this.mitigated) {
      changeValue = c.checked ? this.risk.score : 0;
    } else {
      changeValue = -this.risk.score;
    }

    this.riskSelected.emit(changeValue);
  }
}
```

Template:

```html
<mat-list-item fxLayout="row"
               fxLayoutAlign="space-between center"
               class="risk-list-item"
               [class.mitigated]="mitigated"
               (click)="onSelect(c)">

  <div fxLayoutAlign="start center" fxFlex>
    <p>
      <span matBadge="{{ risk.requiresApproval ? 'AR' : ''}}"
            matBadgeColor="accent" matBadgePosition="before" matBadgeOverlap="false">
        {{ risk.description }}
      </span>
    </p>
  </div>

  <div fxLayout fxLayoutAlign="end center" fxFlex>
    <mat-chip-list disabled="true">
      <mat-chip color="primary">{{ risk.score }}</mat-chip>
    </mat-chip-list>

    <mat-checkbox #c color="primary" [indeterminate]="mitigated">
    </mat-checkbox>
  </div>
</mat-list-item>

<!-- MITIGATION NOTES -->
<div *ngIf="mitigated">
  <mat-form-field>
    <textarea matInput placeholder="Mitigation Note:"></textarea>
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you create an example on StackBlitz?

Comment: I'm such a noob, that'll probably take me hours...let me see.

Comment: I can guess that when you click on checkbox itself you switch it state twice because the event is handled by checkbox itself + by `(click)` on list-item. Try to add `style="pointer-events: none"` to the checkbox.

Comment: @Dimanoid, that worked! Thank you. I knew it had something to do with event handling. So you're saying that the browser is handling the click event PLUS the click handler on the containing element, checking it twice (thus unchecking it)?

Comment: @paddyB click event is sent to the element that was clicked, then to it's parent, then to the parent of it's parent and up to the root or until one of the handlers will stop it.

Comment: @Dimanoid - I see. Thanks for the clarification.